# Why can I change my DNS servers on iOS and Android, but not Windows

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, dns, android

I am trying to change my DNS server from OpenDNS (through my router) to Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 DNS service. I am unable to access the router settings, and when I try to change the servers through Windows, I am unable to resolve any sites. This stumped me, but what was even more confusing was that when I install the 1.1.1.1 apps on my Android phone and iOS iPad, I AM able to connect and use the internet normally with no problems, even on the same wifi network. Is there a way to configure this to work on Windows that I am unaware of? I changed the servers in Windows according to the instructions in the picture attached to this post.[image: DNS configuration instructions from the 1.1.1.1 website.]
If it helps, the 1.1.1.1 app installs itself as a VPN, which the device connects to and uses for as long as you have the app enabled.

TLDR: Changing my DNS server works perfectly on iOS and Android, but not on Windows and I'd like to know how to make it work on Windows.

UPDATE: I am able to connect to 1.1.1.1 on Windows, and pinging it works fine.

Comment: If you do have a working networking connection can you ping 1.1.1.1?

Comment: I had trouble using cloudflares dns in Windows, so I gave up on using it, similar to you at times it could not resolve dns.

Comment: Pinging the website works. @Moab, I have had the same troubles with Google's DNS servers too. It seems to be a windows issue or a network issue and not an issue with the services.